# 'toggleClass` - how to `toggle` between 2 different `class` names

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to `toggle` 2 different classes. (A b), but i am not getting the result.
what is the issue with my code?

```js
$('button').on('click', function () {
    $('div').toggleClass("A B");
});
```

```css
div{
    height:20px;
}
.A{
    border:1px solid red;
}

.B{
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<button>Color Change</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give your div a 'starter' class. Otherwise the first will 'toggle both on', the next 'toggle both off' etc.

---

Since both are setting the border, the last applied class is being used, whilst the other is being ignored, so hence you won't see the 'red' border.

Think of it like toggling between *one* class - on or off. If you start with *no class*, then the button will add the class (understandably).

If you're toggling with *two* classes, the same rules apply. You start with *both off*, then the button will toggle *both on* - and due to the order of css applied/specificity of css, the second will overwrite the first css definition.

So, in order to 'switch', you need to start with one in the 'on' position, and one in the 'off' position. And there you go! once the button is pressed, one will toggle from on to off, and the other vice versa.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('div').toggleClass("A B");
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 20px;
}
.A {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.B {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="A"></div>
<button>Color Change</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button').on('click', function () {
    $('div').toggleClass("A B");
});
```

```css
div{
    height:20px;
}
.A{
    border:1px solid red;
}

.B{
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="A"></div>
<button>Color Change</button>
```

Comment: How is this answer different from someone who gave the same answer before? No duplicate answers please.

Comment: @RahulDesai What if we both post the answer at same time? and there is only one answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

No need to toggle both the classes. One class you need to assign and another class you can toggle.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="A"></div>
 <button>Color Change</button>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    $('div').toggleClass("B");
});
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    height:20px;
}
.A{
   border:1px solid red;
}

.B{
   border:1px solid blue;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q1Ldczg0/)

If you seen here the logic is simple. When you click the button it add the additional class called `B` into the `div`. Once you click the button your div code will become like this `<div class="A B"></div>`

So it is important that the order of A and B in your CSS. For example if you move `B class` to the top of `A class` then you won't get the desired result.

**Not working CSS:**

```
div{
    height:20px;
}
.B{
   border:1px solid blue;
}
.A{
   border:1px solid red;
}
```

Otherwise you can use the `important` keyword, so that it will not worry about the order, but not good in the practice.

Comment: I agree with you. the problem is, I am getting the `element` generated from server side, without the class names. in this case how can i manage?

Comment: @3gwebtrain: You might be able to target on the jquery's ready function and append the class on the page load?

Comment: yes, there is bunch of element. as well i don't require the class names always other then they click. I guess on click event putting some condition will do?